# Notification sounds not playing on android

Tags: android, react-native

I am currently using Notifee with Firebase for local push notifications on react-native android, and on debug mode it works perfectly, with my custom sound playing normally. But after assembling a release apk, on some android devices the notification sound simply does not play after a while. I've checked the notification settings on the devices and it's normal, not set to silence and the devices aren't in "do not disturb".

Here's the code :

Channel Creation at index.js

```
notifee.createChannel({
  id: 'service',
  name: 'New Notifications',
  vibration: true,
  sound: 'siren',
  badge:false,
  vibrationPattern: [300, 500],
});
```

Creating the notification

```
const onMessageReceived = async (notification) => {

const { department_name, category_name, activity_name, description, destination} = notification.data;
    const messageToBePresented = `Department: ${department_name}\nCategory: ${category_name}\nActivity: ${activity_name}\nDescription: ${description}\nBed: ${destination}`;
    try {
      notifee.displayNotification({
        title:'New Service',
        body:messageToBePresented,
        data: notification.data,
        android:{
          channelId:'service',
          style: { type: AndroidStyle.BIGTEXT, text:messageToBePresented },
          pressAction: {
            id: 'default',
          },
          sound:'siren',
        }
      });
  }
  catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  }
}

 firebase.messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
 firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceived);
```

Is there some Android setting that i might i've overlooked that causes notification sounds to stop playing ?